# Rerunning groups of tests in xunit for diferent program modes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

I have a program which can run in three modes, each of which have somewhat different operational logic, and a different data set.

I am adding unit testing to this project using XUnit, and would like to have a set of tests that fires once for each of the program modes.

I could do this using [InlineData()] for each test with a range of values from 1-3, and then select each mode from an array. However, the problem with this approach is that *switching mode takes around 20 seconds, and I'd rather have my set of tests run once for each of my three modes, rather than changing modes each time I ran a test.*

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could call a set of tests for N different modes, each with a different data set, only switching once for each mode?

Comment: have a base type and 3x concrete versions is the normal way

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I have ended up using inheritance as you suggested. If you put as the answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, one addresses sort of concern by implementing the test as a (normally `private`) Test Method in an `abstract class`, and then make concrete derived classes per configuration you're interested in using - the test will run per concrete class.

You can share state between tests in each class or across them using [the relevant various xUnit mechanisms](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context).